# Angular how to make reusable buttons

Tags: html, angular

Good afternoon everybody.

Let me better explain the situation.

In a `myComp.html` I got the instance of some dropdown-buttons from another component `<app-myButtonsFromAnotherComponent></app-myButtonsFromAnotherComponent>`.

The dropdown-buttons are being displayed correctly BUT when I try to get the script which they are originally connected `myButtonsFromAnotherComponent.ts` they do not seem to communicate at all with it (I am using a Getter function in the `.ts` but it doesn't retrieve the datas) and at the same time, because of the instance, I cannot access their values from `myComp.html` either, I can just display the buttons on the screen and display the values through `{{theValueInQuestion}}` int their **original** HTML file.

Can anyone, please, help me to get those values and use them in my script?

PS Why "reusable" in the title? Because in such a way I can keep those buttons in a separate component and let other components grab them without copy and paste a ton of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two separate components you need a way to communicate between components.
you can look more into :

- Localstorage
- Output() and EventEmitter
- Parent to Child via Input

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you mean that I would need all these elements to make it work or just one of them?

Comment: Just one of them. See https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs for parent/child component communication.

Comment: Thanks a lot I gonna have a look at it.